# Is it bad form to treat argument names the same as variable names in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I define a function in javascript, I frequently name the place holder what I would like them to be. This leads to the problem that, declaring those arguments as variables in the function makes them have the same name. Is this a problem (because I do not often see it done).

For example:

```
var words = 'Hello there';

var talk = function talk (words) {
  // Realizing this does nothing, I am leaving it in because other answers refer to it. 
 var words = words;
 //I suppose this could also be this.words = words?
 console.log(words);
}

talk(words); //To log "hello there"
```

This is an extreme example, but in many instances it seems like this would make more sense than using similar and not quite correct words (like `var letters = words`)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `var words = words;` -- this accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the function parameter (`words`)?

Comment: Imagine yourself reading production code that follows what you just outlined there and ask yourself if that's something you want to encounter. Depending on what you answer, you just might survive in the team of programmers.

Comment: @Shomz, not sure there is any thing wrong with it, I just rarely see the function parameters named the same as previously declared variables and was unsure why

Comment: having the same variable as argument is fine as long as they don't share the same scope.. but this can create confusion to other programmers;

Comment: Last time i checked this fails in safari on the latest iOS (think i found the problem on an IPad Air 2). The value of the parameter is overwriten by the value of the outer scope variable with the same name when inside the 'talk' function scope. (only here i found the problem and i think it's a bug, but you can avoid it by not using the same name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a principle for readability, it is best to avoid unnecessary confusion.  In your example, if your var-words was a deep copy of words that was then modified, then what would get printed?  Even if you know the answer, will your fellow developers?  Will they actively go and find out the correct answer before modifying the code?  Especially in the case of javascript where it tries to make all code as runnable as possible, it could lead to undefined behaviour and bugs.

In most scenarios this wouldn't need to happen because you should be naming your copies appropriately, or not having them at all if they don't serve a purpose that deserves a new name (such as sortedWords, or duplicateWords, fiveLetterWords, etc)

If you HAVE to do as your extreme example states, the best I can come up with is changing the argument variable name to "words_argument" or something similar to avoid confusion.

Edit:  seems like OP edited the question to remove the 'var words = words' line within the function, which is what most of my answer was referring to

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid variable hoisting in JS because this could lead to a bigger problems

refer to these links:

http://thecomputersarewinning.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: There is no danger from hoisting here, and there was also none before the question was edited.

Comment: I see, var words = words was removed